# How do I batch convert images from sRGB to CMYK with a specific ICC profile?

Tags: image-processing, convert

I have a few hundred sRGB .tif files that require conversion to the CMYK FORGRA52 ICC profile. I tried using the software XnConvert, but this doesn't work (I don't think it supports conversion from RGB to CMYK). Note I have a copy of the FOGRA52 ICC profile, which I was using as the output profile in XnConvert.

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and prefer a GUI solution if possible, but I'm willing to use the commandline provided the commands are explained clearly.

I previously used Adobe software on Windows, but have since migrated to using darktable for photo processing.

Comment: Welcome, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50672867/6005145) on stackoverflow. The utility is called `imagemagick`, I think it is installed by default in Ubuntu, at least 20.04.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity  Looks promising, but I lack the commandline skills to try it out just yet- I'm a beginner in that regard. Much appreciated though, thanks for the comment.

Comment: Maybe you can seek help on stackoverflow for your specific needs, using imagemagick, but be aware that there folks tend to be a little grumpy :|